# Constant integrals over fixed-length arcs of the circle

Tags: real-analysis

Let $0<\alpha<1$ be irrational. Suppose we have some integrable function $f\colon[0,1]\to\mathbf R$ with $f(0)=f(1)$, which we think of as a function on the circle $S^1\subset\mathbf{C}$. If the integrals of $f$ over all arcs of $S^1$ of length $\alpha$ are zero, so that
$$\int_x^{x+\alpha}f(t\bmod1)e^{2\pi it}\,dt=0$$
whenever $x\in[0,1]$, must $f$ be zero almost everywhere? Or can we at least guarantee that the integrals of $f$ over all arcs of length between $0$ and $1$ are equal to zero?

**What I've tried.** One thought I had was to apply the above identity with points that are close to each other repeatedly to get the equalities
$$\int_x^{x+\epsilon}f(t)e^{2\pi it}\,dt
=\int_{x+\alpha}^{x+\alpha+\epsilon}f(t)e^{2\pi it}\,dt
=\int_{x+2\alpha}^{x+2\alpha+\epsilon}f(t)e^{2\pi it}\,dt
=\dots,$$
and then somehow use the fact that the sequence $\{\alpha\}, \{2\alpha\}, \dots$ is dense or equidistributed on $[0,1]$, but I don't know how to proceed on this front. Another idea was that, if $f$ is continuous, then we can use the above equalities to see that $f$ is periodic with period $\alpha$, since
$$f(x+\alpha)
=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\frac{1}{\epsilon}
\int_{x+\alpha}^{x+\alpha+\epsilon}f(t)e^{2\pi it}\,dt
=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\frac{1}{\epsilon}
\int_x^{x+\epsilon}f(t)e^{2\pi it}\,dt
=f(x).$$
Since $f$ is also periodic with period $1$, it then follows that $f$ must be constant and thus zero everywhere. But I'm not confident about the rigorous details of this case, and I still don't know what to do about the general case when $f$ is merely integrable.

Thanks.

Comment: Update: my friend proved that if $f$ is everywhere bounded, then we must have $\int_x^{x+\epsilon}f(t)\,dt=\int_y^{y+\epsilon}f(t)\,dt$ for all $x,y\in S^1$ and $\epsilon>0$. See https://boonsuan.github.io/misc/yuelin_bounded.pdf